# Looping and inserting based on individual column values SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, insert

The table in question is `Purchases (pid, cid, pdate, eid)` where `pid` is the primary key and thus represents an individual purchase. `cid` represents the customer of the purchase. I have to get all of the customers who have over 5 purchases, and give them all a free ticket (create a new entry for that `cid`). Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: goodluck to your homework... bloody schools aye!

Answer (score 0):

Do an inner join on the the tables (if you need the name of the customer) and group by CID 
HAVING COUNT(CID) > 5

Answer (score 0):

When writing complex SQL queries, one of the best approaches is iterative development... start small, and work from there.

For example, get count of purchases for each customer that had at least one purchase:

```
 SELECT p.cid
      , COUNT(1) AS cnt_purchases
   FROM purchase p
  GROUP BY p.cid
  ORDER BY p.cid
```

Note the usage of the `GROUP BY` clause and the aggregate `COUNT` function.

What if we wanted that same result, but wanted to exclude customers that had only one purchase? We can include a condition on the result of an aggregate function in a `HAVING` clause.

For example:

```
 SELECT p.cid
      , COUNT(1) AS cnt_purchases
   FROM purchase p
  GROUP BY p.cid
 HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
  ORDER BY p.cid
```

Should be easy to see how we would exclude customers that have fewer than five purchases.

These are patterns we need to know before we try to tackle more complex problems.

(The question doesn't include *any* SQL, and gives no indication that there is any understanding of how to get a "count per" using `GROUP BY` or aggregate functions.)